# Number of times the ball bounces back when dropped from a building of height h

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I need help in calculating the math behind the below question.

> A child plays with a ball on the nth floor of a big building the height of which is known . He lets out the ball. The ball rebounds for example to two-thirds of its height.
>
> His mother looks out of a window that is 1.5 meters from the ground.

**How many times will the mother see the ball either falling or bouncing in front of the window**

> **Note**
>    You will admit that the ball can only be seen if the height of the rebouncing ball is stricty greater than the window parameter.

Example:
h = 3, bounce = 0.66, window = 1.5, result is 3

What i have learnt is

> I know that the ball falls from 27 feet and bounces back up 2/3 of that height, so I multiplied 27 times (2/3) and got 18 feet for the height of the first bounce.
>
> Then, since it went up 18 feet, it fell from 18 feet
>   for the second bounce and bounced back up 2/3 of 18 feet. A table showing the four bounces:

1. Bounce 1:  (2/3) * 27 feet =   18 feet
2. Bounce 2:  (2/3) * 18 feet =   12 feet
3. Bounce 3:  (2/3) * 12 feet =    8 feet

I dono from this , how to reach solution ?

Comment: Can you express the height of the bounce after $n$ rebounds easily -- something of the form $a\cdot r^n$, maybe? (Also, for the sake of the reader (and your own) sanity, stay consistent with units. If the mother's window is in meters, phrase everything in meters!)

Comment: can you explain clearly please  @ClementC.

Comment: Say that at the $n$th rebound, the ball will go up to height $a\cdot r^n$ (for $a,r$ known constants you will have to figure out). Let $N$ be the smallest integer such that $a\cdot r^n \leq 1.5$. That means that whenever $n\geq N$, the mother will not and cannot see the ball anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An answer**

Let's start by defining some variables. Let $h$ be the height, $b$ be the percentage of the height which it bounces, and $v$ be the maximum possible height the ball is visible to the mother.

Every time the ball bounces, we take the height of the ball and multiply it by the bounce $b$. We are doing this repeated, and as you may recall repeated multiplication is exponentiation. So, for $n$ bounces, the height will be $hb^n$, or the height times the bounce factor $n$ times. Now, for the ball to be visible, the height of the bounce must be greater than the variable $v$. From this, we can construct an inequality $hb^n > v$. Now, we can solve for $n$ and round down.

**Example:** $h=3$, $b=2/3$, $v=1.5$ (as stated in your example)

From substitution, we get $3(2/3)^n > 1.5$. We can simplify this to get

$$(2/3)^n>0.5$$

$$log_{2/3}(2/3)^n > log_{2/3}(0.5)$$

$$n > 1.709$$

The ball will bounce $1$ time before it is out of visibility.

We can check this by doing your method

*Bounce 1*: $3 * (2/3) = 2$

*Bounce 2*: $2 * (2/3) = 4/3 < 1.5$

At bounce 2, the ball is no longer visible.

**Formal Solved Equation**

We can even make a formal equation for any $h, b, n, v$.

$$hb^n > v$$

$$b^n > v/h$$

$$log_bb^n > log_bv/h$$

$$n > log_bv/h$$

Which when rounded down gives

$$n = \lfloor log_bv/h \rfloor$$

for $\lfloor\rfloor$ is the floor function, which rounds down a number to an integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such good explanation @Foliar.

Comment: @Jame92 It would help if you could press the check-mark to accept my answer; that way you and i get reputation, and people visiting know my answer is valid and answers the question :)

Comment: I need one more help . The result for the above solution is 3 instead of 1. I am trying to solve but i couldn't . Any idea how to solve this .

Comment: @James92, first of all, the result for the above solutions is **not** 3. I even showed you the result using your method of repeated multiplication. I would like to see the steps you did to get the result of 3. Also, you can use a simple graphing calculator to solve the formal equation

Comment: This is the explanation " I multiply it by 2 because every bounce that makes it to the window counts as seeing the ball rising and falling. I add 1 because the ball is seen falling once on the initial drop."

Comment: 1 + 2 * (int) Math.floor(Math.log(window / h) / Math.log(bounce));